Update Table from another with Many to Many Relation
The following are sample tables to explain what I need to do. I need to update the ActivityDate column of Activity table from StatusDate column of Status table such that if StatusID is X in Status table then set ActivityDate at Activity table for Activity A to that of StatusID 'X' i.e. "01-03-2024" , if StatusID is Y in Status table then set ActivityDate at Activity table for Activites B & C to "15-03-2024" .... etc.
Activity Table:



ItemID
ActivityID
ActivityDate




1
A



1
B



1
C



1
D




Status Table:



ItemID
StatusID
StatusDate




1
X
01-03-2024


1
Y
15-03-2024


1
Z
02-04-2024



Here is the query I tried:
UPDATE Activity
    set  a.ActivityDate=
                    case 
                    when s.StatusID='X' AND a.ActivityID='A' THEN s.StatusDate
                    when s.StatusID='Y' AND a.ActivityID in ('B','C') THEN s.StatusDate
                    when s.StatusID='Z' AND a.ActivityID='D' THEN s.StatusDate
                ELSE a.ActivityDate
                END 

from Activity a
    left join Status s on a.ItemID=s.ItemID 


So what isn't working about your attempt? You reference an object (aliased as) w in your query, but there is no object with that alias/name; is that the problem?

I fixed that error. What happened is only ActivityDate for Activity 'A' was updated, remaining recoreds not updated. So query applied only one case and ignored other cases.

UPDATE Activity should be UPDATE A.

If you run your CASE an a SELECT instead, you'll see what's happening: db<>fiddle

@ db<>fiddle : please clarify

db<>fiddle isn't a person, that's a hyperlink...

Most likely you need to pre-aggregate here. One method would be to use a derived table in an APPLY. As the column ActivityID from Activity is needed for the expression as well you can "cheat" the outer expression by using a VALUES table construct and reference that column instead.
This ends up with something like this:
SELECT V.*
INTO dbo.Activity
FROM (VALUES(1,'A',CONVERT(date,NULL)),
            (1,'B',CONVERT(date,NULL)),
            (1,'C',CONVERT(date,NULL)),
            (1,'D',CONVERT(date,NULL)))V(ItemID ,ActivityID,ActivityDate);

SELECT *
INTO dbo.Status
FROM (VALUES(1,'X',CONVERT(date,'01-03-2024',103)),--Please do not use ambiguous dates
            (1,'Y',CONVERT(date,'15-03-2024',103)),--Please do not use ambiguous dates
            (1,'Z',CONVERT(date,'02-04-2024',103)) )V(ItemID,StatusID,StatusDate)--Please do not use ambiguous dates
GO

UPDATE A
SET A.ActivityDate = SD.StatusDate
FROM dbo.Activity A
     OUTER APPLY (SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN s.StatusID='X' AND V.ActivityID='A' THEN s.StatusDate
                                  WHEN s.StatusID='Y' AND V.ActivityID IN ('B','C') THEN s.StatusDate
                                  WHEN s.StatusID='Z' AND V.ActivityID='D' THEN s.StatusDate
                             END) AS StatusDate
                 FROM dbo.Status S
                      CROSS APPLY (VALUES(a.ActivityID))V(ActivityID) --Gets around the outer reference
                 WHERE A.ItemID = S.ItemID) SD;
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Activity;

db<>fiddle

I tried that in my actual qury but i got this error :   Msg 8124, Level 16, State 1, Line 39
Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference. If an expression being aggregated contains an outer reference, then that outer reference must be the only column referenced in the expression.

The above works fine in my environment (and in the fiddle, as demonstrated), @Hussein , I explicitly state that that error is avoided, due to the use of the VALUES table construct.. It also works in much older versions, such as 2014.  I can't talk for something EoL, but I assume you'd tell us if you're using EoL software. If you're getting that error, I suspect you've changed the query, or there's something else going on.

@ Thom A, the error caused by the statement "ELSE a.ActivityDate" the line before end statement in my query. IS it possible to fix this i think it is normal to add another variable to MAX statement. Thank you for your assisst, Regards

It should be ELSE V.ActivityDate, @Hussein . Note, again, the answer: "As the column ActivityID from Activity is needed for the expression as well you can "cheat" the outer expression by using a VALUES table construct and reference that column instead."
